# jQuery fadein/out on hover/out without flicker or queue

Tags: jquery, queue, tooltip, fadein, jquery-hover

I have a list of HTML elements in a row.  Each list item contains an image inside a hyperlink, like this:

```
<ul class="products">
  <li><a href="#" title="Title 1"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Title 2"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Title 3"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

When you mouse over a list item I essentially want to fade in a tooltip containing the title of the link using jQuery.  So when you mouse over the first list item, the DOM will change to the following:

```
<ul class="products">
  <li>
    <div class="product-title-ribbon">Title 1</div>
    <a href="#" title="Title 1"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Title 2"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Title 3"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

When you mouse out the tooltip needs to fade out.  It's actually going to end up more complicated than a standard tool-tip, hence the reason I'm not just using an off-the-shelf solution; I'm trying to get my head around the mechanics so I can understand it and adapt going forwards.

Anyhow, I have the basics working but it's ugly as the tooltips keep fading in and out as you mouse across the items.  I've done a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YcuYY/.  Can anyone suggest a way to improve this so that the tooltips are much more refined without flickering or queueing?  With this sorted I should be able to continue to adapt it for the end-requirements.

```
var productRibbon = $('<div class="product-title-ribbon"></div>');

$('.products li').hover(function() {
    var productTitle = $('a',this).attr('title');
    productRibbon.text(productTitle);
    $(this).prepend(productRibbon);
    productRibbon.fadeIn(500);
},function () {
    $(productRibbon,this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Many thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't listen to people suggesting that `hover` is wrong. They don't read the jQuery official Documentation.
The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

**And it's totally fine and CORRECT**

I'll just use the `.on` method for simplicity sake and delegate the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Also, I will not iterate over the `element` **productRibbon** cause it's not worthy, I'll append it immediately to every `<li>` inside the each, to prevent jumpy animations:

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/emisem/5/edit)

```
$('.products li').each(function(){     
   $(this).append('<div class="product-title-ribbon">'+ $('a',this).attr('title')+'</div>');      
}).on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ) {    
   $(this).find('.product-title-ribbon').stop().fadeTo(400, e.type=='mouseenter'?1:0);      
});
```

While `.stop()` prevents animation buildups
`e.type=='mouseenter'?1:0` will determine the opacity level depending on the current registered `e` event
And add `display:none;` inside your CSS for `.product-title-ribbon`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the jsFiddle a bit http://jsfiddle.net/3ppqv/

The change was:
1)  CSS - added "display: none" to "product-title-ribbon" class

```
.products li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.product-title-ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 40px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #f00;
  display: none;
}
```

2) JavaScript, made the div a local variable on hover, and changed the selector for fadeOut to use the css class:

```
$('.products li').hover(function() {
    var productRibbon = $('<div class="product-title-ribbon"></div>');
        var productTitle = $('a',this).attr('title');
        productRibbon.text(productTitle);
        $(this).prepend(productRibbon);
    productRibbon.fadeIn(500);
    },function () {
        $('.product-title-ribbon',this).fadeOut(500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use .hover(). edit: use opacity rather than fadeIn/fadeOut, or as pointed out below use stop() instead of stop(1).

```
$('.products li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var productTitle = $(this).find('a').attr('title');

        productRibbon.text(productTitle);
        $(this).prepend(productRibbon);
        productRibbon.stop().animate({opacity:1},500);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find(productRibbon).stop().animate({opacity:0},500);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but if you mouse out and then mouse back in during the fade out it stops in mid-fade. You could something to detect if it is in mid-animation and reverse it though.

Comment: well thats what the stop(1) does, prevents queuing of events. if you don't do that, you'll build a giant queue of fadeIns and fadeOuts. If thats what you want, just remove the .stop(1).

Comment: No, I agree with you, but if you mouseout, and then mouse back in during the fade out it needs to reverse the fadeout so the tooltip isn't half opaque.

Comment: i switched fadeIn(500) to animate({opacity:1},500), doesnt do that half-fade thing. ill fix my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That's not true. **don't use hover** means nothing. `.stop().fadeTo(500,1)` inside a hover will work smooth. The issue is the `element` iteration for every mouseenter, please read the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/hover/) or Stack Overflow will become another W3Schools